# preg_replace(): Unknown modifier 'g' in

Tags: php, mysql, preg-replace

I get this error:

> preg_replace(): Unknown modifier 'g' in

On this code:

> ```
> $text = preg_replace("/\\[img]([^\\[]*)\\[/img]/","<img src=\"\\1\" border=\"0\">",$text);
> ```

Help anyone?

**EDIT:**
My goal with this is when i use

> ```
> [img]http://google.com/img.png[/img]
> ```

in a comment field the output should be something like

> ```
> <img src="http://google.com/img.png"/>
> ```

Comment: There are a few problems with this. What is your goal? It looks like you may be trying to replace `[img]...[/img]` and with a proper `<img>` tag. The unknown modifier error is due to `[/img]` prematurely ending your regex. If we know the input and expected output, we can help more effectively.

Comment: This is for a comment system. When the use [img] in the comment field it will turn to <img>. If you understand. Im not very good at English so excuse me for that :P

Comment: Unescaped `/` indicates end of the regexp, giving switches of `i`, `m` and `g`.... `i` and `m` are actually both valid regexp switches, but `g` isn't

Comment: Please edit your question above to show a specific example of the input and output string., like `[img]stuff[/img]` output as `<img src='stuff' />`

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape all occurances of `/` inside the outer `/` delimiters of your regex.

So you are probably looking for this:

```
preg_replace("/\\[img]([^\\[]*)\\[\/img]/",
             "<img src=\"\\1\" border=\"0\">",
             $text);
```

Otherwise the regex engine will treat the expression as terminated here at the second `/`:

`/\\[img]([^\\[]*)\\[/`

Whatever follows will be treated as modifiers to the expression. `i` and `m` do exist, `g` does not exist. That is why an error is thrown whilst compiling the regex.

Alternatively you can use another delimiter character beside `/`. But you have to make sure that character does *not* occur unescaped inside the expression itself. If the expression is not a literal string but comes from a variable then the `preg_quote()` function comes in handy.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a different start/end regex character (for example: `):

```
$text = preg_replace("`\\[img]([^\\[]*)\\[/img]`","<img src=\"\\1\" border=\"0\">", $text);
```